# Removing empty strings from maps in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val lines: RDD[String] = sc.textFile("/tmp/inputs/*")
val tokenizedLines = lines.map(Tokenizer.tokenize)
```

in the above code snippet, the tokenize function may return empty strings. How do i skip adding it to the map in that case? or remove empty entries post adding to map?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`tokenizedLines.filter(_.nonEmpty)`

Comment: does this filter the result or remove them? I am keen on removing them.

Comment: The filter returns a new collection with no empty strings.

Comment: when i print the tokenized lines post filtering, it still has empty strings in array buffer. Am i missing something additionally?

Comment: As in [scaladoc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD), RDDs are immutable, so you can not modify them in place. And you should avoid mutable data structures as long as possible in Scala. So you may write `val tokenizedLines = lines.map(Tokenizer.tokenize).filter(_.nonEmpty)`.

Comment: You can not remove anything from RDD, its immutable, solution is correct as you can collection filtered data for your purpose and use where ever you want to use map without empty string.

Answer (score 11):

The currently accepted answer, using `filter` and `nonEmpty`, incurs some performance penalty because `nonEmpty` is not a method on `String`, but, instead, it's added through implicit conversion. With value objects being used, I expect the difference to be almost imperceptible, but on versions of Scala where that is not the case, it is a substantial hit.

Instead, one could use this, which is assured to be faster:

```
tokenizedLines.filterNot(_.isEmpty)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `flatMap` with `Option`.

Something like that:

```scala
lines.flatMap{
     case "" => None 
     case s => Some(s)
}
```

Comment: ow lines.flatMap{case "" => Nil  case s => Seq(s)} so ?

Answer (score 0):

```scala
val tokenizedLines = (lines.map(Tokenizer.tokenize)).filter(_.nonEmpty)
```